# Just got a quadcopter, and not sure about a piece that came with it

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, quadcopter

My apologies if this is the wrong forum, but I have seen hot questions about drones/quad-copters from here in the past.

I received a quadcopter recently ([X5C Explorers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MNG37C2)), and it has a piece I can not seem to identify online or in the packaging/manual itself.  It is orange, and appears to have a USB port on one end and an slot for possibly an SD card on the other (not too sure to be honest, but the quadcopter has a camera so probably has something to do with that).  Picture included below.  So any idea what this thing is and more importantly, how it should be used?

[image: SD card slot?].

[image: USB port?]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question does not belong in this SE, however this cable is for uploading pictures from the SD Card (Supposedly from your drone camera) to your computer via USB. You just plug the SD Card in the end it belongs in and plug it into a USB port on your computer.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense.  It just didn't look like something that would plug directly into a computer at first (feels very light), but I suppose that is exactly what it is for.